# Sagepay Protocol 3.00 upgrade notes

Tags: cartthrob, ee

I'm looking to upgrade our Cartthrob 2.2.9 version to bring in the changes required for V3.00 Sagepay. Does anyone have any advice on what i'd need to upgrade for this version? I can see in the Sagepay notes that there are changes to the encryption method which i have successfully implemented on a Cakephp store but need to what requires modification on Cartthrob?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm with Vector, and as Justin says, we are the new owners of CartThrob.

We've just released version 2.62 of CartThrob, which includes support for the SagePay v3 API. You can get it from your "Downloads" area on http://www.CartThrob.com.

Alternatively, if you can't upgrade CartThrob itself for any reason, the updated gateway files are here: http://www.cartthrob.com/free_downloads/payment_gateways/sagePay.zip. Just download them and replace the files in your installation.

*[Edited because this has now been released]*

Comment: thanks @matt - i've since seen the email sent by Vector about the new version and a link to the updated files for older versions.
http://www.cartthrob.com/free_downloads/payment_gateways/sagePay.zip

Answer (score 0):

Currently CartThrob 2.6.1 which is the most recent released version of CT does not support SagePay v3 api. CartThrob recently changed ownership to Vector Media Group ([blog post](https://www.vectormediagroup.com/blog/view/vector-acquired-cartthrob-ct-admin)) which has said on other channels that they are aware of the looming deadline for SagePay api requirements and are working on getting an update out soon.

Having said that I believe that v2.3 of CT requires at least EE 2.6 and that CT2.6 adds support for EE2.8/2.9.